# Trying to change .states with ionic's `on-swipe-right` method. Stuck with an error

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

Forgive me but I have spent the last 3 hours or so trying to work around this issue. I have settled for not passing params and simply just swiping to a new state without passing params just for the sake of getting it done but No Luck!

**THE ERROR.**

> *Error: Could not resolve 'app.current-trip.html' from state 'app.today'
>       at Object.transitionTo*

The **trip-details.html** modal where the on-swipe functions is located...

`<button on-swipe-right="onSwipeRight()"class="button">SLIDE RIGHT to Start Trip</button>`

The **BookingsController.js** - where the app function's logic is located.

```
angular.module('starter')
 .controller("BookingsCtrl", function($scope, $stateParams, $state, $ionicModal, BookingsService, driverLocationService) {

$scope.onSwipeRight = function() {
  $state.go('app.current-trip.html');
}
```

The state routing in **app.js**..

```
.state('app.today', {
    url: '/today/:user_id/:driver_id',
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/today.html',
          controller: 'BookingsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

 .state('app.trip-details', {
    url: '/trip-details',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/trip-details.html',
        controller: 'BookingsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.current-trip', {
    url: '/current-trip',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/current-trip.html',
        controller: 'BookingsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

Does it matter that the current-trip.html is a modal? and not an actual view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the state name, not the template filename. Try:

```
$state.go('app.current-trip');
```